# Recipe for Success

Tags: word-problem, cipher, story

One evening you receive an e-mail from an acquaintance, asking for your help. The e-mail runs as follows:

> Dear friend,
>
> I need your help! I've forgotten the combination to my safe and I need some important documents that are inside. I believe I hid the code in the attached recipe. Here's what I can say (it may or may not help):
>
> - The recipe is written in my handwriting
> - The safe has 6 dials
> - Each dial has values ranging from 1 to 100
> - I have a cousin Alex, and an aunt named Lavinia
> - I remember the default combination was 1-2-3-4-5-6 (that's the same combination I have on my luggage!), but I've definitely changed it since then
>
> Help! I called my dad and he doesn't even LIKE Caesar salad. I'm so confused.

The following recipe is attached to the e-mail:

> Dad's Favorite Caesar Salad
>
> Ingredients
>
> - 1 bag iceberg greens
> - 1 carton Alex's extreme simmered eggs
> - 2 ounces olives
> - 1 ounce shaved parmigiano-reggiano
> - 1 measure Lavinia's dressing
>
> Instructions:
>
> Mix the ingredients in the appropriate order (the amounts are just the start). Get rid of anything Caesar wouldn't recognize, or if the amount is too much. Once mixed, garnish with a crouton (or an anchovy - it's the same).

Can you help your friend out?

HINT 1:

> Follow the 3 steps of the instructions if you have trouble interpreting them, Hint 2 will be more explicit

HINT 2:

> Here are the steps: Get the order correct, then figure out the numbers from the ingredients (Quark has a mostly-right idea), then "garnish".

Comment: First puzzle, so would love comments from people.

Comment: It looks nice, though quite hard.

Comment: Glad it's presenting a challenge. Feel free to ask questions, though my thoughts behind it are probably simpler than the puzzle looks.

Comment: Looks very nice. Is the Alex/Lavinia thing a red herring (or red anchovy perhaps)?

Comment: This email would obviously be in my spam folder.

Comment: Caesar wouldn't recognise iceberg lettuce. It wasn't developed until the late 1940s.

Comment: @randal'thor - yes, the Alex/Lavinia comment is a red herring (though in the "recipe" they are both used in determining the combination)

Comment: Added a couple hints - Hint 2 is not completely explicit, but provides some specific steps.

Answer (score 3):

Attempt at a glance:

> 2, 73, 59, 60, 13, 64

Method:

> First, a focus is placed on "get rid of anything Caesar wouldn't recognize", basically look for the roman numerals. The names Alex and Latvinia seem to purposely contain a majority of roman numerals (i=1, v=5, x=10, l=50). The "or if the amount is too much" is what I assume to mean throw away any values 100 or over. Caesar ciphers normally involve adding to values which is why I add the values in the 6 ingredients (olives used twice) on top of the original 1,2,3,4,5,6.

Bit messy of an answer because not too confident about it.

Comment: This is partially correct, but not entirely. You're not using all of the instructions (they are all used).

Comment: Perhaps the garnish would be to add 7 (number of letters in anchovy,crouton) to each number?

Answer (score 1):

Leaving only the roman numerals (IVXLCDM) of this:

```
1 bag iceberg greens
1 carton Alex's extreme simmered eggs
2 ounces olives
1 ounce shaved parmigiano-reggiano
1 measure Lavinia's dressing
```

Gives you many numbers that aren't valid, mostly because of the `mcd`.  Since one of the clues is to remove anything that is too much, get rid of these digits and just use the ones that are `ivxl`.

> i = 1, 
>  lxxi = 71,
>  liv = 54,
>  viii = 8,
>  lviii = 58,

The only thing similar between a crouton and an anchovy are the number of letters.  Thus, I propose the combination is:

> 1 71 54 8 58 7

This doesn't take into account the amounts - perhaps they are not needed?  Also, it doesn't make any attempt at re-ordering.

***EDIT***: Corrected the 4th number.  Also, if we perform the same operation on anchovy, and crouton, we get:

> anchovy -> cv, crouton -> c

These are different numbers, so I don't think we can use this operation, unless there is a mistake?

Comment: You got the numbers mostly right  - you missed a roman numeral in the parmesan one and the last one is wrong (do the same thing to that as the other numbers), but you do need to do some reordering to get it completely right. Pay attention to the language in the first instruction. There's a cryptic-type clue in that one.

Comment: Made an edit, but still can't resolve anchovy (cv) and crouton (c).

Comment: Note that the instructions say "they're the same" for the garnish. So what's the same between them?